# How to sum integers from 1 to n

Tags: sum, int

I must  sum of the even integers between 1 and ' n ' (inclusive). For example for n = 5 program return 6(2+4). How to make it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `select sum(i) from generate_series(1,5) as t(i) where i % 2 = 0`

Comment: `sum(first n even numbers) = n * (n+1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0
for (i in n):
     if (i.IsEven()):
         a += i
return a
```

or something like that, also you can substitute iseven() for something simple like checking `i%2  ==0`

Answer (score 0):

```
1..5 |> Enum.filter(&(rem(&1, 2) == 0)) |> Enum.sum
```

(In elixir. You didn't say which language.)